# Snapchat login Kit with python

Tags: python, authentication, python-social-auth, snapchat

I'm trying to generate a Oauth URL with python and able to generate but when I hit the URL from Snap I'm getting only "***Something went wrong***" and no other message or error...
[image: Snapchat login window]

Below is my snapchat with python code

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote


SNAPCHAT_API_KEY = "#####################"
SNAPCHAT_API_SECRET = "##################"

SNAPCHAT_OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "https://localhost:3000"


class SnapchatAPI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = SNAPCHAT_API_KEY
        self.api_secret = SNAPCHAT_API_SECRET
        self.oauth_callback_url = SNAPCHAT_OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL
        self.permissions = ["display_name", "external_id"]
        self.auth_url = "https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/auth"

    def snapchat_login(self):
        try:
            query_param_string = urlencode(
                {
                    "client_id": self.api_key,
                    "redirect_uri": self.oauth_callback_url,
                    "response_type": "code",
                    "scope": " ".join(self.permissions),
                },
                quote_via=quote,
            )

            # if state:
            #     query_param_string += f"&state={state}"

            return f"{self.auth_url}?{query_param_string}"
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
```

The url that I'm getting is...

```
https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/auth?client_id=##############&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ftwitter&response_type=code&scope=display_name%20external_id
```

What is the issue here and how can I fix it? Alternatively is there a better way to implement Login with Snapchat with python?